# Indexing dataframe with last known Index of element

Tags: python, lambda

Apologies title isn't very clear, below is an example where "Last Known Index" is a column added to the dataframe that indicates the most recent appearance of ColumnA string.  If it hasn't appeared before, the current index is simply carried.

[image]

I've tried with the below using lambda and am having difficulty filling in the ??? part to drill down the query:

```
df["Last Known Index"] = df["ColumnA"].apply(lambda x: df.index[(df["ColumnA"] == x) & ???])
```

Appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
import pandas as pd
d ={'ColumnA':['AAAA','BBBB','CCCC','DDDD','AAAA','EEEE','FFFF','BBBB','AAAA']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


df = df.reset_index().sort_values(by='ColumnA')
df['index'] = df['index'] + 1 #So it is like in your example
df['Last Known Index'] = df.groupby('ColumnA')['index'].shift().fillna(df['index'])
df.sort_index()
```

Output:

```
   index ColumnA  Last Known Index
0      1    AAAA               1.0
1      2    BBBB               2.0
2      3    CCCC               3.0
3      4    DDDD               4.0
4      5    AAAA               1.0
5      6    EEEE               6.0
6      7    FFFF               7.0
7      8    BBBB               2.0
8      9    AAAA               5.0
```

Please tell me if there's something that you're not understanding

Comment: Hrmmm thanks a lot! I know this works with the snippet I provided, but it's part of a larger time series table with lots of other columns; and row order integrity needs to be preserved as the original index ties to dates, hence using lambda to effectively do this on a line-by-line analysis basis without any dataframe transformations...

Comment: You never lose the original index, I added `+1` because your aren't zero indexing in your example. You can then `df = df.set_index(df['index']).sort_index()` and your dataframe will keep the exact ordering it initially had. If your data is large `lambda` expressions aren't very recommended, because they are slower. This way is faster and there's no risk of losing any data